# Unit tests not found when inheriting from DatabaseEnabledTestsBase

Tags: c#, unit-testing, orchardcms

I'm having issues running Orchard unit tests on Visual Studio 2015 Professional.

When a test class inherits from DatabaseEnabledTestsBase, Visual Studio becomes unable to find the tests in that class.

Reproduction:

1. Install NUnit to the test module. I used v3.6.1.
2. TokenizerTests in Orchard.Tokens/Tests does not inherit from DatabaseEnabledTestsBase. After installing NUnit to the module, I can right-click on TestGlobalTokens() and Run Tests, at which point the test runs and passes.
3. FieldIndexServiceTests in Orchard.Projections/Tests inherits from DatabaseEnabledTestsBase. After installing NUnit to the module, right-clicking on StringValuesShouldBePersisted() and doing Run Tests, the output window displays 'No tests found to run.'

I've tested solutions suggested by similar questions, including:

- Clearing the user/temp directory
- Changing the processor architecture between x64 and x86
- Changing version of NUnit on the modules
- Cleaning the solution
- Restarting VS
- Restarting the PC

Removing the inheritance of DatabaseEnabledTestsBase on FieldIndexServiceTests, along with related functions, makes the tests visible to VS again, though of course the tests no longer pass without database access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make the tests work properly by downgrading the NUnit reference to version 2.5.10.11092 instead of the newest version.